# Github migrate repo to organization and keep branch personal

Tags: git, github

I have a public personal repository on Github. It has the following branches:

```
master
2.x
3.x
```

The master branch is currently the release branch and it is based of the 2.x branch.

I am building new features in the 3.x branch with breaking changes - however it is not ready to be public as yet (again due to things breaking).

I want to transfer this repository to an organization and work separately on the 3.x branch privately in my account.

What would be a good strategy to separate them? Any help is appreciated. If this post belongs elsewhere - please direct me and I will post it there.

Comment: You could copy the `.git` folder to a new project folder. Remove the branches, change the remote to the one of your organisation and push there.

Comment: @ClémentPéau more details please - I am a beginner with these things.

Comment: In github you can (in the organization) make a fork of the public (user) repository. The fork will be private. Develop in the fork. When ready, make a PR in the public repo to incorporate the changes from the fork.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud super just tested it out. Now the only issue is that I have already been working on 3.x in this branch. How do I remove that before transferring to organization and yet keep a copy to put back in my own branch?